# INNER JOIN y GROUP BY en la misma sentencia SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xampp

tengo un problema usando JOIN y GROUP BY a la vez, tengo dos tablas (inspecciones y municipios)
Con JOIN quiero mostrar los datos de la segunda tabla (municipio) pero veo que por el GROUP BY me borra ese resultado de la consulta :(

```
 SELECT inspeccion.Municipio as municipio, 
    COUNT (*) AS Incumplimientos, 
    SUM (CASE preguntas.estado WHEN 'ALTA' then 1 else 0 END) AS Criticos 
    
FROM municipios, inspeccion_pregunta, preguntas, preguntas_categoria, inspeccion
INNER JOIN municipios m ON inspeccion.Municipio = m.id
WHERE inspeccion_pregunta.INSPECCION_id = inspeccion.id_inspeccion 
AND inspeccion_pregunta.PREGUNTAS_id = preguntas.id_preguntas 
AND inspeccion.Municipio = municipios.id
AND inspeccion_pregunta.cumple = 'NO' 
AND preguntas_categoria.id_pre_cat = preguntas.PREGUNTAS_CATEGORIA_id

GROUP BY inspeccion.Municipio
```

Esa salida obtengo, pero realmente quiero obtener el nombre del municipio con INNER JOIN
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una idea alocada sería usar la columna que contiene el nombre del municipio en vez de la que tiene su identificador.

Comment: ¿ *inspeccion.Municipio as municipio* es un id? al hacer esto aquí ```ON inspeccion.Municipio = m.id``` me da la sensación. Si es así cambia la columna por el nombre del municipio ```columna_nombre_municipio as municipio```.

Comment: @LuisCazares muchas gracias, al principio lo apliqué pero no me funcionó pero volví a insistir y sirvió

Comment: @DBE cambié a municipios.nombre en el select y group by, y me funcionó perfecto. Mil gracias a ustedes dos

Comment: Me alegro amigo, recuerda aceptar tu respuesta, así queda cerrada la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `SELECT` cambié la columna `inspeccion.municipio` (que era el id del municipio) por `municipio.nombre` (que es el nombre del municipio en la otra tabla) y lo mismo en el `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT municipios.nombre as municipio, 
    COUNT (*) AS Incumplimientos,  incumplimientos
    SUM (CASE preguntas.estado WHEN 'ALTA' then 1 else 0 END) AS Criticos 
    
FROM municipios, inspeccion_pregunta, preguntas, preguntas_categoria, inspeccion  
INNER JOIN municipios m ON inspeccion.Municipio = m.id
WHERE inspeccion_pregunta.INSPECCION_id = inspeccion.id_inspeccion 
AND inspeccion_pregunta.PREGUNTAS_id = preguntas.id_preguntas 
AND inspeccion.Municipio = municipios.id 
AND inspeccion_pregunta.cumple = 'NO'
AND preguntas_categoria.id_pre_cat = preguntas.PREGUNTAS_CATEGORIA_id
AND inspeccion.fecha BETWEEN '2010-07-30' AND '2022-07-30' 
GROUP BY municipios.nombre
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]