# ¿Cómo evitar datos duplicados al usar DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mariadb

Tengo una consulta que filtra información, pero se repite dos veces y eso que tengo la palabra clave `DISTINCT`, y aún se sigue repitiendo y no quiero que se repitan.

Esta es mi query:

```
select DISTINCT p.id, 
       p.name, 
       p.price, 
       t.PriceOriginal 
FROM product P
INNER JOIN tvt_preciopromocion t ON  t.ProductId = p.id
WHERE p.id = 24
```

Esta es la imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de los datos de cada tabla par tener un [mcve]?

Comment: La tabla producto tiene demasiados datos, por eso lo simplifique para que sea entendible.

Comment: Hay no hay ninguna información duplicada. Ni es ningún error. `PriceOriginal` es distinto en ambas filas. ¿Qué precio debería de mostrar para que solo hubiera una fila? Lo que buscas no es `distinct` es `group by`.

Comment: de la misma manera simplifica los datos, te recomiendo leer el articulo [Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [INNER JOIN y GROUP BY en la misma sentencia SQL SERVER](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/532274/inner-join-y-group-by-en-la-misma-sentencia-sql-server)

Comment: Es como dice Javi fer2: `DISTINCT` afecta filas completas. Las dos filas son diferentes, porque tienen precios diferentes. Si quieres una sola fila para cada ID tienes que decidir qué precio quieres mostrar. ¿El máximo precio quizás? ¿O la suma? ...

Comment: Y por favor solamente usa una etiqueta para el DBMS que uses. Obviamente tienes una base de datos en un DBMS. No uses MySQL y PostgreSQL y MariaDB. He removido todas estas etiquetas. Por favor use una sola etiqueta para el DBMS que realmente uses.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner no saques las etiquetas que estan mal.. en su lugar, espera que OP ponga las etiquetas correspondientes.. yo vi la publicacion, y lo primero que pense es que faltaba decirnos para que base de datos...

Comment: @gbianchi: Okay. Es como lo hacemos en stackoverflow inglés, porque pasa a menudo que contestadores escriben respuestas para uno de los DBMS en los etiquetas y finalmente es otro DBMS, y la respuesta no funciona, y el trabajo era en vano.

Comment: Aca antes de contestar, pedimos que aclaren que DB es.. Tratamos de no contestar cosas que no estan bien claras... tenemos un [chat] por si queres aclarar dudas.. Bienvenido y gracias por la ayuda!!!